# R Shiny: code output inside markdown table cell

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, knitr

I'm trying to embed R lot output inside the cells of an html table. This is as far as I've got:

**app.R**

```
require(shiny)
require(knitr)
require(ggplot2)

d = iris

ui = fluidPage(
  uiOutput('markdown')
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$markdown <- renderUI({
    HTML(knit(text = paste(readLines('table.html'), collapse='\n')))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**table.html**

````
<table class='table'>
<tr> <th>text field</th> <th>sparkline</th> </tr>
<tr>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</td>
  <td>
```{r, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE}
# message("setosa") # uncomment to test console output
qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = d[d == "setosa",], geom="line")
```
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</td>
  <td>
```{r, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE}
# message("versicolor")
qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = d[d == "versicolor",], geom="line")
```
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</td>
  <td>
```{r, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE}
# message("virginica")
qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = d[d == "virginica",], geom="line")
```
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
````

This outputs as follows:
[image]

knit is outputting the graphics to file. Is there a way to get them to render directly instead?
I may be going about this wrong but have not identified an equivalent {rmarkdown} workflow..

---

As a related point when testing with the `message(...)` output instead of qplot the html table cell looks like this:

````
``` ## setosa ```
````

Any idea how to remove the backticks and hash symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working toolchain is as follows:

#### table.Rmd

````
<!--pandoc
t: html
o: table.html
-->

```{r, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
opts_knit$set(base.dir = "www")
```
<table class='table'>
  <tr>
    <th>text field</th>
    <th>sparkline</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
    </td>
    <td>
      ```{r, echo = FALSE, include = TRUE}
      qplot(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, data = d[d$Species == "setosa", ], geom = "line")
      ```
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
````

#### app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)

d <- iris
ui <- fluidPage(
   uiOutput("markdown")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$markdown <- renderUI({
      tmp <- knit("table.Rmd", quiet = TRUE) ## could combine these...
      pandoc(tmp)                            ## ...two lines also in `knit2pandoc`
      includeHTML("table.html")
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Then you can run `runApp("app.R")` and you get the following output:

[image: RMD in Shiny]

### Some remarks

This was trickier than I thought and I am by no means a `pandoc/knit/markdown` expert, so not even sure whether I get the nomenclature right, but I can share what I found out:

- I changed your `table.html` into a `table.Rmd`, because, well, it is in fact an `RMarkdown` and not a (pure)  `HTML` file. If we want (as in my example) work with file names rather than `readLines` this is also necessary to help `knit` to use the right  delimiter tokens.
- I ran `knit("table.Rmd")` to see how the `markdown` document looked like and it seemed to be OK.
- My next thought was to use `includeMarkdown` on this `.md` file but after some trial and error, I found out that for whatever reason the translation from `.md` -> `.html` (that's what happens under the hood for `includeMarkdown`) did not work and the markdown token `![plot](path/to/figure)` was never properly translated to teh according `<img>` tag. The same happened when I tried to use `knit2html`. Both rely on `markdown::renderMarkdown` and this function simply does not translate the markdown image token to an HTML image token **if nested in a table**.
- Looking into standalone `rmarkdown` docs, I see that they make use of `pandoc` to translate the `markdown` document to an `HTML` format.
- After some more trial and error I could convince `pandoc` to produce the results:

  - I added some `pandoc` configuration into the `table.Rmd`. However, since these are anyways the defaults you can also safely ignore them. If you want to do some more fancy stuff, you will need them to tweak the way `pandoc` is called.
  - `shiny` expects static resources to be hosted under the `www` folder. Thus we need to tell `knit` to use this folder to store the figures (another option would be to use `addResourcePath` on the `shiny` side).

#### TL;DR

The following toolchain will work:

```
table.Rmd -> table.md via knit -> table.html via pandoc -> shiny via inclueHTML
```

or equiavlently

```
table.Rmd -> table.html via knit2pandoc -> shiny via includeHTML
```

---

### `renderMarkdown` does not like chunks in a table

````
does_translate <- "```{r}\nggplot2::qplot(1, 2)\n```"
does_not_translate <- "<table><tr><td>\n```{r}\nggplot2::qplot(1, 2)\n```\n</td></tr></table>"

cat(knit2html(text = does_translate, fragment.only = TRUE))
# vs.
cat(knit2html(text = does_not_translate, fragment.only = TRUE))
````

---

### Update

As per the comments, if you want to ensure that the file names generated in teh chunks are "unique" you can use the following code chunk in your `Rmd` (inspired by [this article](https://community.rstudio.com/t/image-filename-in-rmarkdown-generated-files/28885)):

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, include = FALSE}
opts_knit$set(base.dir = "www")

knitr::opts_chunk$set(
   fig.process = function(filename) {
      wd <- dirname(filename)
      ext <- file_ext(filename)
      new_filename <- tempfile(tmpdir = wd, fileext = paste0(".", ext))
      file.copy(filename, new_filename)
      unlink(filename)
      ifelse(file.exists(new_filename), new_filename, filename)
   }
)

```
````

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much @thothal. Clearly some effort went into this. Only thought: I note this generates a file at `www/figure/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png`. I wonder about risk of multiple simultaneous users clashing with the same file (e.g. when their `d` object is different data). Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not an expert of how `shiny` shares the space among different users. You could configure `pandoc` to create standalone html files though. In  this case, pictures are `base64` encoded and not included via a link. Assuming that `shiny` does not take care of this, you could also assign random names to the figures generated by the chunk. Will include an example for this.